# how to add shell commands to postInstall and preInstall in grunt-rpm plugin

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, rpm, rpmbuild

Following the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-rpm) I was able to setup the grunt task and make a successful build.
Now I need to have preInstall and postInstall scripts but I could not find any documentation on how to do that.

This is my setup:

```
rpm: {
            options: {
                // Task-specific options go here.
                name: 'cdrapi',
                version: '1.0.0',
                release: false,
                homepage: 'www.website.com',
                summary: 'api package',
                license: '??',
                distribution: 'CentOS 6.x',
                requires: ['nodejs'],
                preInstall: 'echo "You are in the pre install section"'
            },
            files: {
                dest: '/opt/cdr/api/',
                src: ['**/*', '!**/*.map', '!**/**/*.ts', '!**/bdd_tests/**'],
                cwd: 'build',
                expand: true
            }
        }
```

The above preInstall tag does not do anything, it won't even reflect on the rpm spec file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the argument to `preInstall` and `postInstall` is supposed to be a file not an inline script.

See the code [here](https://github.com/gastonelhordoy/grunt-rpm/blob/master/tasks/lib/default-spec-writer.js#L164):

```
src += readScriptlet('\n%pre', options.preInstall);
src += readScriptlet('\n%post', options.postInstall);
src += readScriptlet('\n%preun', options.preUninstall);
src += readScriptlet('\n%postun', options.postUninstall);
```

and the [readScriptlet](https://github.com/gastonelhordoy/grunt-rpm/blob/master/tasks/lib/default-spec-writer.js#L108) function:

```
function readScriptlet(label, scriptFile) {
    var src = '';
    if (scriptFile) {
        var options = {
            encoding: scriptFile.encoding || 'utf8'
        };
        var data = fs.readFileSync(scriptFile.src, options);
        src += label + '\n';
        src += data.trim() + '\n\n';
    }
    return src;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for looking deeper in the source code, I will remember next time to look there.